# Nobel prize in literature 2018 - what is "encyclopedic passion"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, collocation

The question is inspired by the today's announcement of the Nobel prize awards in Literature for 2018 and 2019.

The short description for Olga Tokarczuk has been worded as follows:

> The Nobel Prize in Literature 2018 was awarded to Olga Tokarczuk "for
>   a narrative imagination that with **encyclopedic passion** represents the
>   crossing of boundaries as a form of life."
>   [Source](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/literature/2018/summary/)

The expression *encyclopedic passion* sounds really odd both to me and to the author of this question on Literature.SE: [Understanding this year's Nobel prizes](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11799/understanding-this-years-nobel-prizes), which, in fact, inspired me to ask for help on English.SE.

I will simply quote one paragraph from this question:

> I can't make sense of terms like "encyclopedic passion". "Encyclopedic
>   knowledge" is a common phrase that I understand. Encyclopedias are the
>   books where one finds the most knowledge. So this term makes sense to
>   describe someone who has vast knowledge. But I do not understand the
>   relationship between encylopedias and passion.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/encyclopedic), for example, gives:

> adjective [usually ADJECTIVE noun]
>   If you describe something as encyclopedic, you mean that it is very full, complete, and thorough in the amount of knowledge or information that it has.

and

> encyclopedic in British
>   or encyclopaedic (ɛnˌsaɪkləʊˈpiːdɪk)
>
> adjective
>
> 1. of, characteristic of, or relating to an encyclopedia
> 2. covering a wide range of knowledge; comprehensive

So, how exactly shall one interpret (*perceive, digest*) **encyclopedic passion**?

Comment: Since when did "lit crit" have to make any sense? :)

Comment: It's garbletalk like "conversation around". From context, it appears to mean "doubleplus good".

Comment: encyclopedic ame, encyclopaedic bre

Answer (score 10):

***[Passion:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/passion)***

> If you have a passion for something, you have a very strong interest in it and like it very much.
>
> - She had a passion for gardening. [+ for]
> - Anton has a consuming passion for science

(Collins Dictionary)

***[Encyclopedic:](https://www.yourdictionary.com/encyclopedic)***

> Embracing many subjects; comprehensive:
>
> - “*an ignorance almost as encyclopedic as his erudition”* ( William
>   James )

(AHD)

> comprehending a wide variety of information; comprehensive:
>
> - an encyclopedic memory.

(Dictionary.com)

> An *encyclopedic passion* > *a passion for a wide range of knowledge*.

Comment: I agree, +1. See [my related answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/11804/793) on Lit.se as well. I think that the word "encyclopedic" is very important, too: "encyclopedic knowledge" implies "lots of knowledge about lots of different topics," so "encyclopedic passion" would imply lots of passion about lots of different topics.

Comment: "An *encyclopedic passion* > *a passion for a wide range of knowledge*"  I agree that is what was intended, but the original does not say "knowledge"; you invented that yourself.

Comment: @GEdgar - encyclopedic - “covering a wide range of knowledge; comprehensive” Collins Dictionary

Comment: Could you give another example of "[adjective] passion" where the current usage implies the meaning "passion for [adjective] things" ?

Comment: @loonquawl - what is that you find difficult to understand? The expression is quite intuitive.

Comment: @user067531 is "wild passion" a passion for wild things? Is "strangled passion" a passion for strangulation? Can you give another example of "[adjective] passion" where the current usage implies the meaning "passion for [adjective] things" ?

Comment: ... philatelic passion? That might work - i'd understand it as a passion for stamps.Is there a linguistic difference between adjectives like 'philatelic' and 'hot'? - and where does encyclopedic stand on that?

Comment: @loonquawl - encyclopedic here means comprehensive, it is used to underline  the very wide range of interests that characterizes the writer.

Comment: @loonquawl Wideranging, all encompassing, philatelic, equine, erotic, focused, quintessential, ... .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thanks! 'philatelic', 'erotic' and 'equine' (i found philatelic myself) would fit in the pattern  of "[adjective] passion" = "passion for [adjective] things"; But 'wideraning', 'focused', 'quintessential' do not (or do they? is 'focused passion' a passion for focused things?) - 'Erotic' might straddle some middle ground incidentally - the passion might be erotic, or it might be a passion for erotic things, or some mixture, does it not?

Answer (score 6):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encyclopedic) has perhaps the most useful and broadest definition:

> **encyclopedic**:
>
> of, relating to, or suggestive of an encyclopedia or its methods of
>   treating or covering a subject : COMPREHENSIVE
>
> an encyclopedic mind
>
> an encyclopedic collection of armor

So 'encyclopedic passion' is probably intended to be read as a wide-ranging, catholic spread of things in which a deep interest is taken. In a less formal register, being 'into everything'.

Comment: *This* is the danger of coining new phrases with existing words.

Comment: @DavidM This is the *beauty* of being able to coin new phrases. Practically all of language evolved using metaphors like this.

Comment: @Barmar It was a reference to a comment by Edwin on a post of mine.  https://english.stackexchange.com/a/514457/59527

Comment: Humpty Dumpty was a crypto-descriptivist.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same feeling as you.  The use of *encyclopedic* with *passion* is a bit odd.

The meaning I would ascribe to it is that Olga Tokarczuk has a passion for encyclopedias and that her bookshelves are groaning under the weight of the various editions of Chambers' *Cyclopedia* or Diderot's and D'Alembert's *Encyclopédie* she's been patiently collecting over the years.  For all I know, that could be it, bibliomania comes in many forms, but I doubt it.

They would have been better off saying she has *a passion for knowledge* but the phrase is a bit clichéd and the Stockholm luminaries probably wanted to avoid it.

Comment: I don’t think that encyclopedic here is literal, it does not refer to a supposed passion for encyclopedias. It is simply figurative, like in encyclopedic memory, encyclopedic mind etc.

Comment: @user067531  I understand.  "Encyclopedic passion" meaning passion for everything.  That poor woman must be exhausted at the end of the day !

Comment: Just as "encyclopedic" is not intended literally, neither is "passion". They're both a bit of hyperbole.

Answer (score 1):

This is amusing. It is the kind of word a child might choose from a dictionary or thesaurus before has acquired a deep knowledge of the language he is using. I doubt that this is the case however. My thesaurus gives comprehensive as an alternative for encyclopedic. That is an appropriate adjective for knowledge but not for the list of vegetables in a garden or for a butterfly collection and certainly not for anybody's passion. We know what the writer meant so let us smile and move on.

Comment: :) I was planning to expand the question and ask for comments/analysis on `imagination that ... represents the crossing of boundaries as a form of life` bit... I don't think it's worth it, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad choice of word because "passion" is to do with emotions or affect whereas "encyclopedic" has to do with knowledge or instruction. Word meanings do change over the centuries but gradually and not because an individual is not fully conversant with the language used. Did Humpty Dumpty write that. Remember him from Alice in Wonderland?
“When I use a word,” Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone , “it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less.”